# Limit @Feeds to one post per X minutes

Tags: feature-request, chat

If there are some feeds configured for one chat room and one of those feeds dumps a lot of new entries it clutters up the chat completely.

For me the point of the feeds is to spark some discussion in the chat room and provide some ambient information.

Massive dumps that "Spam" the chat room don't serve that purpose and just require cleanup attention. [One sample moved away from the php chat where +10 feed entries where dumped at once (again)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1995480#1995480)

My first idea was to limit @Feeds to post only one feed entry per `time` but maybe there are other ways to work around this.

This may happen due to SO pulling the feed not often enough but from what I've observed it usually comes from the feed being down for some time or just dumping massive amounts of entries at once.

It's for sure nothing crucial but it would make the feeds feature more usable if there would be a way to resolve this.

Some more examples:

- [Example one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2110910#2110910)
- [Example two](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2252856#2252856)

Comment: Maybe hide up the extra feeds or simply show a list of feed names which can be expanded/compacted by user?

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to show feeds as a slide-down ticker especially meant for feeds with high volume

[image]

Comment: The feed isn't "high volume". it has about 3-10 posts a day. The issue is that they tend to all show up at once instead of one at a time (and thats is not SO's fault but something that could be fixed there maybe). But it's an option to consider. Thanks :)